# Generated element with Inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'd like to create a generated element with inscape. For example consider this element:

[image: generated element]

It is composed of multiple shapes and texts. It should have these generation properties:

- position, size (as regular element)
- header, content, footer texts

It has to be per-file, not as some add-on or plugin. I don't want to rely to some add-on, even when it's custom-made. I want to have SVG file completely self-contained (it may use Inkscape specific stuff). I don't fear of some scripting!

*Disclaimer: I know about possibility, that I can duplicate it and modify it. If it would be acceptable solution, I would not ask such question,...*

Answer (score 0):

SVGs are XML-based and thus it is comparably easy to write a program that autogenerates the desired SVGs for you (if I understand you correctly).

The easiest way to achieve this is to creat a sample SVG and take its source as a basis which your program modifies as desired.

You may also want to take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/793322/203639), which is very similar to yours but focused on text.